# employee department wise and count of employees more than 5

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to display `department_id`'s along with count,and count should be more than 5, and i want to have employees who are not hired in January.

i tried the below query

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN
 (
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
    FROM EMPLOYEES
   GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*)>5 
 )
AND HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%';
```

but here I didnt get count.I want count Also.

Comment: Of course you didn't get the count, you never selected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT department_ID, count(employee_id) as '# of Employees' FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN
 (
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
    FROM EMPLOYEES
   GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*)>5 
 )
AND HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%'
group by department_ID;
```

This query returns the department_id and because I group by department_id, the count of employees that belong to each department will be returned

Output will look something like this

```
  Department_Id | # of Employees
        1             7
        2             6
        4             9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dept id and count of employees (where employee hire date is not in Jan) then something like the following should work. I say "something like the following" because I suspect the WHERE hire_date NOT LIKE '%JAN%' could be improved, but it would just depend on the format of that column.

```
   SELECT
      DEPARTMENT_ID, 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    WHERE HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%' 
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>5;
```

If you also want to list the individual employees along with these departments, then something like this might work:

```
SELECT a.*, b.count(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEES AS a 
INNER JOIN (   
SELECT
      DEPARTMENT_ID, 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    WHERE HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%' 
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>5) AS b
ON a.department_id = b.department_id
WHERE a.HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%';
```

Again, though, I think you can leverage your schema to improve the where clause on HIRE_DATE. A like/not-like clause is generally going to be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

Select the count from your inner query and *join* to it:

```
SELECT E.*, DEPT_COUNT
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN (
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(*) DEPT_COUNT
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 5 
) DC ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = DC.DEPARTMENT_ID
AND HIRE_DATE NOT LIKE '%JAN%'
```

Comment: I think the joined table also needs to have a hire_date not like Jan, no? Otherwise the count(*) will include employees hired in Jan. It's not entirely clear from the question if the count should include all employees or employees not hired in Jan, but intuitively it seemed to me that it should probably exclude Jan hires for the count